# Deterministic way to generate char array

Tags: c

I want to generate a random char array of 20 characters with the following property

```
SUM( a[i] * (i+1) ) = GOAL
```

I am currently using the kind of brute force approach like below, but it takes too long:

```
int LENGTH = 20;
int GOAL = 14895;

char allowed_chars[] = {48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
char finalarray[LENGTH];    

 srand(time(NULL));

 while(1)
 {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        finalarray[i] = allowed_chars[rand() % (strlen(allowed_chars) + 1)];
        sum += (int)finalarray[i] * (i+1);
    }
    if (sum == GOAL)
    {
        printf("Found: %s", finalarray);
        break;
    }
 }
```

It is generating output, but is there any deterministic way to do this without brute force or hit and try?

Comment: first decide which language, c or c++

Comment: What do you mean? What makes you not to be happy with your code?

Comment: you may want to look at fisher-yates

Comment: Using this approach is time consuming, so I wanted to know is there any deterministic way to generate array that can satisfy the condition, quickly

Comment: c and c++ are two different languages with different possibilities e.g. in c++ there is more std support for random values according to various distributions.

Comment: Ok, then in such a condition, kindly help me with C codes

Comment: @user2370419 It's more of a memory than time-consuming approach. You could replace the array with branching.

Comment: Apart from the bozo-sort characteristics, there are probably some conceptual errors: You have 36 allowable chars, but pick only from the first 20. You should also null-terminate your `finalarray`, which should have ´LENGTH + 1` chars to hold the terminating null character.

Comment: @MOehm: I can pick any char from array (any 36 allowed char), here I am just picking 20. The main constraint to follow is, final array length must be 20 and it must match with the GOAL value.

Comment: @MOehm : Updated the main post

Comment: It is legal to pick only from the first 20 chars, it just looked like a typo. You can't use `strlen` on the allowable chars, because it isn't null-terminated. In this case, you can use `sizeof`, though. Adding 1 to the radom pick is wrong; it may pick a letter one after the array.

Comment: Please don't deface your question.  If you want to remove it, please delete it rather than editing it.

Comment: @Tejash please don't suggest edits that deface the question.  If you feel that this question should be removed, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target sum is always the same, you can find one string that sums up to your goal and then shuffle it in a way that the weighted sum doesn't change.

A string with 20 Gs (ASCII 71) will yield:

```
asc('G') · N · (N + 1) / 2 = 14910
```

This exceeds your goal by 15 and reducing the fifth letter by 3 gives the valid string `"GGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"`.

Now we perform repeated alterations, each of them maintaining the weighted sum. Pick two letters at (one-based) indices `a` and `b`. We can maintain the weighted sum by adding a multiple of `b` to `a` and by subtracting a multiple of `a` from `b`. We must take care that the resulting values are allowed characters, however. If a letter pair can't be altered, pick a new one.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define GOAL 14895

int isum(const char *str)
{
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    while (*str) sum += i++ * *str++;

    return sum;
}

int valid(int c)
{
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') return 1;
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return 1;
    return 0;
}

void scramble(char str[], int n, int m)
{
    static const int delta[8] = {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4};

    while (m) {
        int a = rand() % n;
        int b = rand() % n;
        int i;

        int poss[8];
        int nposs = 0;

        if (a == b) continue;

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int d = delta[i];
            int aa = str[a] + (b + 1)*d;
            int bb = str[b] - (a + 1)*d;

            if (valid(aa) && valid(bb)) {
                poss[nposs++] = d;
            }
        }

        if (nposs) {
            int d = poss[rand() % nposs];

            str[a] += (b + 1)*d;
            str[b] -= (a + 1)*d;

            m--;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int l = 10;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (l--) {
        char str[] = "GGGGDGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG";

        scramble(str, 20, 100);
        printf("%s %d %d\n", str, isum(str), GOAL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This approach is not very clean, because it just does a certain number of alterations and then decides it is enough. A test run yields the following strings, which look random enough at first glance:

```
SM1V52JF0VRIVVHT9B1Q 14895 14895
LC478LEIF2YOV5E3MUQD 14895 14895
R0AEHKDUPSGRIB27CCSM 14895 14895
RL2IGA09N5WJZFY447VY 14895 14895
EI43PYAEKUMVAADE2MPC 14895 14895
1DP4ENJ6CLE3M1WUC2VW 14895 14895
1042WA9TTJTVXRO20X3F 14895 14895
MI4FDKO76SB59D9RWJLS 14895 14895
SLK428RCBZ0YIDV6OJEF 14895 14895
3IJ2TKJ9K4WVQBBYFGG4 14895 14895
```

Answer (score 1):

> but is there any deterministic way to do this without brute force or hit and try?

If the goal is to select 20 of those numbers giving the sum 14895, one way to do it would be *[backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)*.

Basically you start adding values until you are either above the goal or used more than 20 numbers. In that case, subtract the last value, and take the next one. Do this recursively until you either hit the goal or have exhausted all possibilities.

Choosing random numbers generated by an unknown PRNG is a bad approach since it may not test all possibilities and thus fail to find a solution.

PS: What is it you want to do? This looks a bit like finding hash collisions for a simple hash function...

Comment: Sum is generated by multiplying the char value with it's position values too.
sum += (int)finalarray[i] * (i+1);

Is there any example for this situation with backtracking?

Comment: @user2370419 Same idea, just replace the value to add by the product. Backtracking is an extremely general algorithm to solve such problems.